# How to solve "IndexError: index -201 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 200"? in line 3

Tags: python

I run a code and I am getting this IndexError in line 3. how i should solve it?

```
    def treatment_var(means_data, err_data, steps, name):
    ind_end= len(means_data)
    while means_data[ind_end-1] == np.nan or means_data[ind_end-1] == 0.0:
        ind_end -= 1
    plt.errorbar(steps[:ind_end], means_data[:ind_end], yerr=err_data[:ind_end], fmt='o-', color='b')
    if 'baseline' not in name:
        if 'scalar' in name:
            means_b, std_errs_b, steps_b = read_csv_scalar('../eval/eval_scalar_baseline')
        else:
            means_b, std_errs_b, steps_b = load_other('baseline')
        plt.errorbar(steps_b, means_b, yerr=std_errs_b, fmt='o-', color='r', elinewidth=0.8, linewidth=0.8, mew=0.4, ms=4)

    plt.xlabel('Treatment time (h)')
    plt.ylabel('Dose (Gy)')
    plt.xlim((-10, steps[ind_end-1]+10))
    plt.ylim((-0.1, 5.1))
    plt.savefig('tmp/' + name + 'var.pdf', format='pdf')
```

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments, not in title) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: in `while`-loop you runs `ind_end -= 1` so finally you get `-201` but `means_data` has only 200 elements. You have to check `int_end` inside loop and exit this loop when `ind-end` is too small

Answer (score 0):

In `while`-loop you runs `ind_end -= 1` so finally you get `-201` but `means_data` has only `200` elements and it can gives only `-200`.

You have to check `int_end` in this loop

```
while (ind_end > -len(means_data)) and (... or ...):
```

or rather you should use only positive values

```
while (ind_end > 0) and (... or ...):
```